# Etiquette for responding to other answers once I've chosen one?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Sometimes when I ask a question that is probably relatively easy for the more advanced programmers on this site, I'll receive a handful of answers in the span of a few minutes.

Occasionally, a few will ask for clarification of what I'm looking for, ask why I want to do things a certain way, etc. but one person will know exactly what I'm asking and give a great answer. This is the answer I usually choose right away.

I typically ignore the rest of the answers at this point, especially if they've directly asked me for more information. Is it discourteous to refrain from providing more explanation or engaging in discussion once I've chosen an answer that solves the problem? On the one hand, people took the time out of their day to attempt a solution to my problem. On the other, however, there is obviously someone who understood what I meant and the question has been answered so likely no longer holds any relevance to the other answerers.

Comment: Asking for clarification should be made as a comment, not an answer. Feel free to choose the answer that helped you the best.

Answer (score 10):

There *may* be a problem if others are asking for clarification into the matter, but let's get some things straight.

- Requests for clarification should *only* be in comments, not in answers.  That is, if someone asks you what you're asking in an answer, **they shouldn't be answering.** Neither you nor anyone looking at your answer later wants incomplete responses.
- Ignoring the rest of the answers is a huge mistake, especially considering that they may provide other approaches or other techniques to solve the problem.  It's *fine* to accept the one that helped you best, but don't ignore that wealth of knowledge.

It's important if you have a decent number of people asking you for more clarification to come back and clarify your question, since you don't want to have someone answer your question and have it be *wrong* because you weren't clear with your requirements.  That also matters for others that may read your question and subsequent answers in the future.